# mail and mailx fail to send emails to gmail

Tags: snow-leopard, terminal, email

Quite frequently I have to send the outputs of my work on terminal (e.g. when compiling code) to my colleagues via email. I was wondering if it is possible to pipe (`|`) the output of a terminal command directly to email and I realized there are `mail` and `mailx` that can be used for this purpose.

The problem is, when I try a simple message like this

```
ls -laF | mailx -s 'generated files' colleague@gmail.com
```

nothing is sent. How should I tackle this problem? In [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53913/how-can-i-send-smtp-mail-via-gmail-and-osx-lion-mailx) post a very similar situation is asked and something is suggested but it's not the solution anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X has postfix installed by default but it's not enabled (started). You can start it with

```
sudo postfix start
```

you can check the status and eventual problems in `/var/log/mail.log`

The configuration is in `/etc/postfix/`

Comment: Thank you. I started `postfix` as you said and tried again and failed again! checking the log it is telling me 

`[my ip]:25: opration time out`

any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any firewall?

Comment: I tried from home and it seems it is working. Probably it was a problem with internet connection at my work palace. Just one last question, should I `stop postfix` after or I can leave it running?

Comment: You can leave it running. I would look online for the manual and check the configuration but as far as I remember the default settings are OK.